# What Excel function constructs and returns a reference to a range of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am already familiar with Excel's `address` function, which takes two integers representing a row and a column and returns a reference to the specified cell. For example, `=address(2,4)` gives `$d$2`. Is there a built-in Excel function that does for cell ranges what `address` does for individual cells -- something like `=func(2,4,6,8)` or `=func(address(2,4),address(6,8))` which can return `$d$2:$h$6`?

These are my failed attempts at a workaround so far:

- `=address(2,4):address(6,8)`: The syntax is invalid.
- `=address(2,4)&":"&address(6,8)`: There is no syntax error, but because Excel treats the return value of this formula as a string, it is not usable by other functions as a range reference. For example, `=countif(address(2,4)&":"&address(6,8),">10")` does not actually give the same result as `countif($d$2:$h$6,">10")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use INDIRECT :

`=countif(INDIRECT(address(2,4)&":"&address(6,8)),">10")`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the offset function:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(D2,0,0,4,3), ">10")
```

defines a range starting at D2 that is 4 rows and 3 columns. The two 0's can be used to move the start location from D2, so entering D2,1 will move to D3 etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to dynamically populate the parameters in `Ron Rosenfeld's` answer using calculations, you can avoid the usually obnoxious change from a column's number to its letter by using the following approach:

```
=INDEX(2:2,,4):INDEX(6:6,,8)
```

which gives the same D2:H6 but uses a number for the column rather than a letter in the parts of the range.

(And although there is a simple way to get the column letter, no one seems to know it and defaults to the obnoxious divisions by 26 and so on. Thing is, the easy way STILL ivolves adding a bit while the above goes at it pretty directly.)

Comment: Good point about solely using numbers.  But I think many who have worked solely in Excel find it simpler to use Letters for columns, which is why I did it that way.  By the way, since each of your `INDEX` array arguments are a single row, you can omit the extra comma. `=INDEX(2:2,4):INDEX(6:6,8)` works the same.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: (1) You’re missing the point.   The question is about how to access a rectangular range *given the **coordinates*** of the corners.   We can use Jeorge’s answer simply by plugging in the numbers from the question.   To use your answer, we have to translate 4 → D and 8 → H.   This is relatively easy to do manually (at least for numbers ≤ 26), but totally impractical to do automatically if the column number is the result of a formula / calculation (e.g., a call to `MATCH()`). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) Your statement about leaving out the blank field (omitting the “extra comma”, as you put it) seems to be correct, but I can’t find it documented.   How did you know about that?   Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Scott *Can you provide a reference?* Look at **HELP** for the function. It's pretty clear there.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Thanks for responding.  OK, I looked, and it is “clear” by Microsoft standards; i.e., as slightly dilute mud.  It’s my position that you read an ambiguous statement and interpreted it the way the author intended; i.e., you got lucky.  (Or you think like a Microsoft tech writer; that’s not something I would brag about.)  Anyway, thanks for contributing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with the commonly used `INDIRECT` and/or `OFFSET` methods is that they are both volatile functions. That means they recalculate whenever the worksheet is recalculated, even if such would not be necessary.  On a large worksheet with many such formulas, this can be time consuming.

You may be better off using the non-volatile `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX($D:$D,2):INDEX($H:$H,6)
```

will return a reference to `D2:H6`

**Note**
Something you need to be cognizant of:

The various formulas provided will react differently to insertion and deletion of rows or columns in or before the affected ranges.  In some cases, they will continue to refer to the original range at its new location; in others they won't.